# How to disable angular material component in 2.0.0-beta.5

Tags: angular, angular-material

Updated material and currently have this error getting thrown

```
Error at /Users/asaylor/Desktop/RevenueIQ/website/aot/node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.ngfactory.ts:4236:30: 
Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'MdCheckbox'
```

also getting this for other material components. I don't see any documentation on their releases about changing the way a component is disabled. What's the correct way now?

Comment: where is the code you tried. Error message alone is not enough to fix

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` is a valid property

```
  <md-checkbox class="example-margin" [disabled]="disabled" [color]="primary">
    Disabled
  </md-checkbox>

  <button (click)="disabled = ! disabled"> Toggle disable</button>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/IBpJlOIskaO4YTSMpQTq?p=preview)**

Comment: I think it should be  `[disabled]="true"`